# Can't set appropriate dtypes reading from a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search

I would like to save some attributes of a dataframe and given a slice of the underlying numpy array, I would like to rebuild the dataframe as if I had taken a slice of the dataframe. If an object column has a value that can be coerced into a float, I can't figure out any method that would work. In the real dataset, I have millions of observations and several hundred columns.

The actual use case involves custom code where pandas interacts with scikit-learn. I know the latest build of scikit-learn has compatibility with pandas built in, but I am unable to use this version because the RandomizedSearchCV object cannot handle large parameter grids (this will be fixed in a future version).

```py
data = [[2, 4, "Focus"],
        [3, 4, "Fiesta",],
        [1, 4, "300"],
        [7, 3, "Pinto"]]

# This dataframe is exactly as intended
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# Slice a subset of the underlying numpy array
raw_slice = df.values[1:,:]

# Try using the dtype option to force dtypes
df_dtype = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_slice, dtype=df.dtypes)
print "\n Dtype arg doesn't use passed dtypes \n", df_dtype.dtypes

# Try converting objects to numeric after reading into dataframe
df_convert = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_slice).convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
print "\n Convert objects drops object values that are not numeric \n", df_convert
```

```
[Out]
 Converted data does not use passed dtypes 
0    object
1    object
2    object
dtype: object

 Converted data drops object values that are not numeric 
   0  1    2
0  3  4  NaN
1  1  4  300
2  7  3  NaN
```

EDIT:
Thank you @unutbu for the answer which precisely answered my question. In scikit-learn versions prior to 0.16.0, gridsearch objects stripped the underlying numpy array from the pandas dataframe. This meant that a single object column made the entire array an object and pandas methods could not be wrapped in custom transformers.

The solution, using @unutbu's answer is to make the first step of the pipeline a custom "DataFrameTransformer" object.

```py
class DataFrameTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.columns = list(X.columns)
        self.dtypes = X.dtypes

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        X = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=self.columns)
        for col, dtype in zip(X, self.dtypes):
            X[col] = X[col].astype(dtype)
        return X
```

In the pipeline, just include your original df in the constructor:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([("df_converter", DataFrameTransformer(X)),
                      ...,
                     ("rf", RandomForestClassifier())])
```

Comment: Are you trying to save `raw_slice` to disk?

Comment: Note that in this case there is not "an underlying numpy array". There are two because numpy arrays are homogeneous. Hence, there is an underlying int64 array and an object/string array. When you do values you're effectively concatenating them into one array, and it has to be object because one of the component arrays is object.

Comment: I didn't know that. Very good information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to save a slice of a DataFrame to disk, then a powerful and
convenient way to do it is to use a `pd.HDFStore`. Note that this requires
PyTables to be installed.

```
# To save the slice `df.iloc[1:, :]` to disk:
filename = '/tmp/test.h5'
with pd.HDFStore(filename) as store:
    store['mydata'] = df.iloc[1:, :]

# To load the DataFrame from disk:
with pd.get_store(filename) as store:
    newdf2 = store['mydata']
    print(newdf2.dtypes)
    print(newdf2)
```

yields

```
0     int64
1     int64
2    object
dtype: object
   0  1       2
0  3  4  Fiesta
1  1  4     300
2  7  3   Pinto
```

---

To reconstruct the sub-DataFrame from a NumPy array (of object dtype!) 
and `df.dtypes`, you could use

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[2, 4, "Focus"],
        [3, 4, "Fiesta",],
        [1, 4, "300"],
        [7, 3, "Pinto"]]

# This dataframe is exactly as intended
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# Slice a subset of the `values` numpy object array
raw_slice = df.values[1:,:]

newdf = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_slice)
for col, dtype in zip(newdf, df.dtypes):
    newdf[col] = newdf[col].astype(dtype)
print(newdf.dtypes)
print(newdf)
```

which yields the same result as above. However, if you are not saving
`raw_slice` to disk, then you could simply keep a
reference to `df.iloc[1:, :]` instead of converting the data to a NumPy array of
object dtype -- a relatively inefficient data structure (in terms of both memory and
performance).